# Can i use a domain name on a subsite?

Tags: sharepoint-online, sub-site, domain, dns

**Background:** Our company is using SharePoint. We have now created a subsite which is related to a club. The club just bought a domain name, and we want to promote the domian name, so that people go directly into the clubs subsite.

**Question:** Is it possible to use a Domain name on a subsite?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Which version of Sharepoint you are using?

Comment: Office 365 Enterprise E3(SharePoint Online (Plan 2))

Answer (score 0):

**As you are using Sharepoint online there is no such possibility.**

For on Prem there is this feature called hosted site collections. (and this is used in SHarepoint online but you cannot manage it and you can have just one url per tenant. Apart from few test to see i never used in site collection.

Have read through this article it should give you a good start:
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/kaevans/2012/03/27/what-every-sharepoint-admin-needs-to-know-about-host-named-site-collections/

REf: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/lync/en-US/d4328551-eab1-44c6-b4e7-b3b424ab9ff3/use-of-host-named-site-collections-in-sharepoint-online?forum=sharepointadmin